# Android - How to create a NxN layout dynamically, like Tic Tac Toe?

Tags: android, layout

How can I make a layout dynamically like tic tac toe?

It must be dynamical because I want to make 3x3 squares, or 4x4 squares, or nxn squares.

I think I need 2 `for-loops` to do it, but what exactly and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use GridView which is simple to use but available only from api 14, or you can place n LinearLayouts in each n LinearLayouts which you can do in any api.

Here is a sample I made for nXn layouts should work(just replace the big_layout with the view you want this attached to).

```
public void createNxNLayouts(int n,int width,int height){
    LinearLayout[] main_layouts = new LinearLayout[n];
    for(int i=0;i<main_layouts.length;i++){
        main_layouts[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        main_layouts[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        main_layouts[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height/n));
        bigLayout.addView(main_layouts[i]);
    }
    LinearLayout[][] secondary_layouts = new LinearLayout[n][n];

    for(int i=0;i<secondary_layouts.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<secondary_layouts[i].length;j++){
            secondary_layouts[i][j] = new LinearLayout(this);
            secondary_layouts[i][j].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            secondary_layouts[i][j].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/n,height/n));
            main_layouts[i].addView(secondary_layouts[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i was thinking about it, but I don't know how to do it, how the inside view of each linear layout will have the right width and height, etc... do you have some example?

Comment: Here I added a sample

Comment: what can i pass in width and height?

Comment: @DouglasFornaro the width and height of the board, note that I edited the code a bit

Comment: Is there a way to do it without specify the width and height? And build a square occupying all the space? Always creating squares. Like this: if device is portrait build the width all the space so height will have the same value, if device is landscape build the height all the space so width will have the same value.

Comment: This doesn't compile. What is ``bigLayout``?

Answer (score 0):

GridView seems to be the best option. It will work well even if the number of items change during runtime.

However, if you want to avoid GridView, Use a RelativeLayout as a parent and position the views of the child layouts as a grid using [LEFT_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#LEFT_OF) and [BELOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#BELOW) similar properties.

A RelativeLayout would be better than hierarchy of LinearLayout as nesting of views may be bad. ([Ref](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html))